# How to remove list element from an array after searching

Tags: c#

I wanna to remove list element from my array..but I am not getting the solution ..
this is my code..

```
for (int k = 0; k < name.Length; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list_emp_info.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime resigndate = Convert.ToDateTime(list_emp_info[i].ResignDate);
        if (resigndate <= DateTime.Now)
        {

            name[k] = name[k].Remove(list_emp_info[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Linq

```
list_emp_info = list_emp_info.Where(l=> Convert.ToDateTime(l.ResignDate) > DateTime.Now).ToArray();
```